# NODE JS Project Demo

Tags: node.js, web-applications, demo

I have a toDo web application made in NODEJS. I want to include it in my resume and want 2 links , one for project code and other for project demo ? Is there any way to show live demo of this nodejs project just like we can have github pages for a frontend project ?

Comment: you can deploy it on heroku

Answer (score 1):

To show the code, you can put the github link, and for the demo, you have to host your site, for example on AWS or Azure. But these hosting are not free and I don't know if it's possible to host a Node.js site for free

Answer (score 0):

When I hosted my first site, Heroku was the easiest of the free options I looked at. Today I think Netlify is easier.